# How to send complex message headers using citrus test frame work

Tags: citrus-framework

As of now according to the information mentioned in the citrus documentation we can send header using element tag .I have a header like this

```
<usr><scenarioname>xx</scenarionname><instanceID>xx<<instanceID><usr>
```

I am sending the above header using follwing send action

```
   <send endpoint="helloServiceEndpoint">
        <message>
            <payload>
                <TestMessage>
                    <Text>Hello!</Text>
                </TestMessage>
            </payload>
        </message>
        <header>
            <element name="scenarioname" value="xx"/>
        <element name="instanceID" value="xx"/>
        </header>
    </receive>
```

But I want to post a complex header which not just like name value pairs but the header contains nested xml elements. how can i achieve this using citrus

example of complex header

```
     <usr>
<scenarioname>xx</scenarionname>
<instanceID>xx<<instanceID>
<parameters>
<basicauthentication>
<username>xxxxx</username>
<password>xxxx</password>
</basicauthentication>
.
.
.
.
.

</parameters>
</usr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `element` is for `name-value` pairs only. You need to use the `data` element in the `header` section in order to add a complex header fragment.

```
<send endpoint="helloServiceEndpoint">
    <message>
      <payload>
        <TestMessage>
            <Text>Hello!</Text>
        </TestMessage>
      </payload>
    </message>
    <header>
      <data>
        <![CDATA[
        <usr>
          <scenarioname>xx</scenarionname>
          <instanceID>xx</instanceID>
        </usr>  
        ]]>
      </data>
    </header>
  </send>
```